# /bin/sh: 0 cannot open ./configure during install libnet-1.0.2a

Tags: sh, libnet

I have downloaded **libnet-1.0.2a.tar.gz** and tried to install it with the following steps.

Location of libnet-1.0.2a.tar.gz:

```
/usr/nembuild
```

Now unpacking it and changing directory:

```
tar -xf libnet-1.0.2a.tar.gz
cd Libnet-1.0.2a
```

The next commands are for configure and installing:

```
./configure make && make install
```

but here I got this error message:

> /bin/sh:0 Can't open ./configure

What can I do next? Please show me the correct path of installing libnet-1.0.2a.tar.gz.

Comment: What do you get if you type `ls` instead of `./configure make`? What is the output of `pwd`?

Comment: from `ls` I got:
`755           config.status   example           Makefile.in  util
acconfig.h    config.sub      include           misc         VERSION
acinclude.m4  config.sub-new  install-sh        ports        version.h
aclocal.m4    configure       lib               README
config.cache  configure.in    libnet-config     src
config.guess  doc             libnet-config.in  support
config.log    ensure-dir.sh   Makefile          test
`

Comment: from `pwd` I got:
`/usr/nembuild/Libnet-1.0.2a`